# Access Remote machine files in host machine

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-server

I have my machine (windows 7) and i got a remote machine (windows server 2012) and i can map the host machine drive in the remote connection, but i would like the opposite navigate the drive in the host machines, how can i achieve that?

My main goal is to use my IDE in the host machine to alter some code on my virtual machine and not have to install anything on the server

I tried

> \\servermachine\c$ or just \\servermachinename\

i get actually some authentication requests but inserrting the right domain user and password i dont seem to be able to open the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the right command was

\\servermachinename\

but the autentication domain was not the same as the domain the machine was cointained. After that it opened a empty folder, and i had to share the folder i wanted inside the remote machine